# making a nav bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I"m trying to make a bootstrap nav bar like this :
[image: img1]
I could manage only this one:
[image: img2]
And here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style type="text/css">
            .nav{
                position: absolute;
                top: 5px;
                right: 190px;
                border-left: 3px solid #EEE;
                border-right: 3px solid #EEE;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#"><img src="./imgs/endorse-logo1.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-header nav">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">English<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Russian</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Chinese</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

It isn't even responsive. How can I make a responsive nav bar properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) you will see that there is a lot of mistakes in your code:

- you have two `navbar-header` element, you should have only one, and multiple `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` elements,
- you need to wrap your navbar elements (`<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`) in a `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">` element in order to  make it responsive,
- you can get rid of your .nav css to fix the navbar top as you are already using `navbar-fixed-top`,
- you are using `<ul class="nav nav-pills">` where you should directly use `<a class="dropdown-toggle">`

etc...

Maybe you should retry to create the navbar from the beginning by following precisely the documentation.